Alembic not recognizing multiple models, using FastAPI
i am using sqlalchemy[asyncio], sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic, asyncmy. my database is mysql and have the following project structure:
core/
├─ database.py
├─ settings.py
alemibc/
├─ versions/
├─ env.py
├─ script.py.mako
models/
├─ users/
│  ├─ user_model.py
├─ notes/
│  ├─ note_model.py
alembic.ini


this is my database.py:
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base
from .settings import settings

# Create the async engine
engine = create_async_engine(
  settings.DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL,
  pool_size=50,          # Start with 50, adjust based on testing
  max_overflow=100,      # Allow up to 100 additional connections
  pool_timeout=30,       # 30 seconds timeout for waiting for a connection
  pool_recycle=1800,     # Recycle connections every 30 minutes
  echo=True              # Set to False in production
)

# Create an async session factory
AsyncSessionLocal = sessionmaker(
  bind=engine,
  class_=AsyncSession,
  autocommit=False,
  autoflush=False,
)

# Base class for our models
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

# Dependency to get DB session in FastAPI
async def get_db():
  async with AsyncSessionLocal() as session:
    yield session


my user model:
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from core.database import Base

class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'users'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = Column(String(30), unique=False, nullable=False)
  email = Column(String(50), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
  password = Column(String(200), nullable=False)


note model:
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from core.database import Base

class Note(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'notes'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = Column(String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
  content = Column(String(30000), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
  author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)


env.py:
from logging.config import fileConfig
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from alembic import context
from core.database import Base
from models.notes.note_model import Note
from models.users.user_model import User

config = context.config

if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = AsyncEngine(
        engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
        )
    )

    with await connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with await context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()


when i run the migrations i get empty upgrade and downgrade functions
"""Initial migration

Revision ID: ae6c8d3aeccc
Revises: 
Create Date: 2024-07-13 00:35:37.358247

"""
from typing import Sequence, Union

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision: str = 'ae6c8d3aeccc'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    pass


def downgrade() -> None:
    pass


i have also problems with the async and await in the run_migrations_online() function when i run it as synchronous by default it gives error so i figured a solution out to put await after the 'with' keyword.
default run_migrations_online() func:
def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )


    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()

error thrown if i run the above default function code:
(notes-app-env) PS F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog> alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Initial migration4"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 636, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 626, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 603, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 236, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 582, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\alembic\env.py", line 81, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\alembic\env.py", line 69, in run_migrations_online
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3276, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3300, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 308, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 620, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\asyncmy.py", line 284, in connect
    await_only(creator_fn(*arg, **kw)),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\test-python-backends\fastapi-blog\notes-app-env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 123, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)

i red almost every stackoverflow and github question but can't figure it out.
i also right now only made the 'notes-app-db' in mysql workbench and aside from that it has no tables or anything

ok so i found out that alembic if used with async db drivers like asyncpg, aiomysql, asyncmy need the env file changed to also be async. so we need to change the whole env.py file to be the one below and than add your models and Base and other stuff.
here is the async template below:
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine
from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = None

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def do_run_migrations(connection):
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = AsyncEngine(
        engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
            future=True,
        )
    )

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    asyncio.run(run_migrations_online())


and run the migrations and it works fine nothing else needs to be changed given it is like my files i mentioned in the question.
here is how you modify the template to be used for more than one of your models or just one:
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine
from alembic import context
from core.database import Base
from models.notes.note_model import Note
from models.users.user_model import User


# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def do_run_migrations(connection):
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = AsyncEngine(
        engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
            future=True,
        )
    )

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    asyncio.run(run_migrations_online())


hope this helps and this is the github issue that i got the template from

Out of curiosity - is there any benefit (apart from convenience, I suppose) in using async drivers for migrations?

@snakecharmerb The only benefit is not installing a new dependency, psycopg2, just to run the sync driver in migrations.

Use the -t async flag for asynchronous support:
alembic init -t async alembic

Then the alembic file "env.py" is already formed, with support for asynchrony, or rather the function async def run_async_migrations(), which allows processing asynchronous functions.
